# VM's Grub menu invisible with XenServer 6.0.2?

Tags: debian, xenserver, grub

I have a dual-boot VM on XenServer 6.0.2 but grub just shows up as a black screen. I can still make a selection and such, but it's just a black screen in the XenServer console. Any ideas on how to make this visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, it looks like this is related to a bug in XenServer [Bug 30978](http://forge.univention.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30978)

The temporary solution I have found is based on a suggestion within the bug comments. It looks like the workaround requires you to switch grub to console mode.

**Solution for Debian 7.4:**

**Manual:**

- Edit: /etc/default/grub
- Uncomment: `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
- Run: `update-grub`

**Automated:**

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i "s/#GRUB_TERMINAL=console/GRUB_TERMINAL=console/g" /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```